# How to reRender panelGroup with Ajax a4j:support

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

Let me start by saying I am obviously very new to ajax / jsf so please excuse me. First I have been reading some of the richFaces docs, and am still not clear on the difference is between 'render' and 'reRender'.

**What I am trying to achieve is** a page with two "areas" that are hidden/ not rendered by default. When the user selects a `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` this would trigger the rendering of the "area" that corresponds to this BooleanCheckbox. This seems to be far more work then it should be and maybe I am missing something very elementary.

Here is my Code.

```
<h:outputLabel for="saveNote" value="Create Note "/>            
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="saveNote" value="#{noteController.saveNote}" immediate="true" >            
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="noteArea"/>                         
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputLabel for="sendEmail" value="Send Email "/>    
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sendEmail" value="#{noteController.sendEmail}" immediate="true">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="emailArea"/>                                                        
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

This is nested inside an `<h:form>`

The "area" I am trying to control the rendering of is as follows...

```
<h:panelGroup id="noteArea" rendered="#{noteController.saveNote}" layout="block">
```

This is also nested inside the same `h:form` as the `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`

Please help, ajax is starting drive me nuts!

Thanks so much in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reRender attribute will a number of client ids to render upon postback.  This is supposed to be the client id, not the server id of `noteArea`.

Unless in your `h:form` element if you have specified `prependId` to be false, the form id will be preceding the panelGroup id in your form to make your unique client id.

```
form1:noteArea
```

Also I don't think you want to set `immediate` to true on the checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! That was a silly mistake, I added `entryForm:noteArea` and removed the `immediate = true`, it still is not working, I suppose there are some other beginner issues I am having, any other suggestions? Thanks again for your quick response!

Comment: @CurtWalker Try inspecting the markup on the page to see what the client id of the `panelGroup` really is.  It will render as a div on the page.  Further, try adding logging statements in the setter of your boolean managed properties to see if they are actually getting set properly.

Comment: Thanks again! That worked, after inspecting the elements the panelGroup was actually a <tr> due to the fact that it was nested inside a paneGrid I suppose? I did the reRendering on the div one level up, a rich:form, and it works nicely now, THANK YOU AGAIN!