# Dynamically show/hide page elements via backing bean method called with AJAX using RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to implement a page that shows/hides elements based on the results of a backing bean method which is triggered by the key up event on an input. What I've written is behaving quite unexpectedly - the content inside my panelGroup does not change at all after page load, and instead a wild span is appearing at the top of the page containing the content I expected to be displayed in my outputText elements. This is a legacy application running on JSF 1.2 and richfaces 3.3, so its possible that this functionality might not be available (hinted at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694450/how-can-i-show-hide-component-with-jsf)). I also apologize for the use of tables, but unfortunately refactoring this big old app to use proper layout with css/divs is outside the scope of this feature request.

Here is my example jstl template which illustrates the problem. The "string1/2 reversed" outputpanels should only show if the string length is greater than 5, and the text in the outputText elements should be updated while typing in the inputs. Instead, the outputPanels stay static, and a new span is created above the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <head>
        <title>ajax test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
            <a4j:keepAlive beanName="AjaxTestBacking" />
            <p />
            <h:form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td >string1:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText style="width: 200px" value="#{AjaxTestBacking.string1}">
                                <a4j:support event="onkeyup" action="#{AjaxTestBacking.updateString1}" reRender="string1panel"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <h:panelGroup id="string1panel" rendered="#{AjaxTestBacking.displayString1Xform}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>string1 reversed:</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:outputText style="width: 200px" value="#{AjaxTestBacking.string1Xform}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </h:panelGroup>                  
                    <tr>
                        <td>string2:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText style="width: 200px" value="#{AjaxTestBacking.string2}">
                                <a4j:support event="onkeyup" action="#{AjaxTestBacking.updateString2}" reRender="string2panel"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <h:panelGroup id="string2panel" rendered="#{AjaxTestBacking.displayString2Xform}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>string2 reversed:</td>
                            <td >
                                <h:outputText style="width: 200px" value="#{AjaxTestBacking.string2Xform}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </table>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the backing bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AjaxTestManager extends AbstractManager implements Serializable {

    private String string1;
    private String string2;

    private String string1Xform;
    private String string2Xform;

    private Boolean displayString1Xform;
    private Boolean displayString2Xform;

    public AjaxTestManager() {
        string1 = "test string 1";
        string2 = "test string 2";
        updateString1();
        updateString2();
    }

    public void updateString1() {
        string1Xform = new StringBuilder(string1).reverse().toString();
        displayString1Xform =string1Xform.length() > 5 ? true : false;
    }

    public void updateString2() {
        string2Xform = new StringBuilder(string2).reverse().toString();
        displayString2Xform = string2Xform.length() > 5 ? true : false;
    }

    public String getString1() {
        return string1;
    }

    public void setString1(String string1) {
        this.string1 = string1;
    }

    public String getString2() {
        return string2;
    }

    public void setString2(String string2) {
        this.string2 = string2;
    }

    public String getString1Xform() {
        return string1Xform;
    }

    public void setString1Xform(String string1Xform) {
        this.string1Xform = string1Xform;
    }

    public String getString2Xform() {
        return string2Xform;
    }

    public void setString2Xform(String string2Xform) {
        this.string2Xform = string2Xform;
    }


    public Boolean getDisplayString1Xform() {
        return displayString1Xform;
    }


    public void setDisplayString1Xform(Boolean displayString1Xform) {
        this.displayString1Xform = displayString1Xform;
    }


    public Boolean getDisplayString2Xform() {
        return displayString2Xform;
    }


    public void setDisplayString2Xform(Boolean displayString2Xform) {
        this.displayString2Xform = displayString2Xform;
    }

}
```

I apologize if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about richfaces here - I'm somewhat of a noob to richfaces ajax, so please bear with me! I shared this code with my colleague who built the app and he is stumped as well. I've searched on google and SO and found a javascript-based answer, but I'm trying to understand how to do this with richfaces components. Other questions: Is the 'rendered' attribute the way to go here with dynamically showing/hiding parts of the page, or should I be using the 'visible' attribute? also, is the 'reRender' attribute on a4j:support supposed to be the jsf/'server-side' id of the element as I originally understood it, or the rendered client-side element ID as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800059/how-to-rerender-panelgroup-with-ajax-a4jsupport)? Just trying to figure out if I'm misunderstanding something, limited by my jsf/richfaces version, or just generally going crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar behavior with JSF 2.1. When a rendered tag is present on an element, and you plan on showing/hiding the element via ajax, you should wrap it with another naming container and rerender the parent container instead. Something like this would do

```
                  <tr>
                    <td >string1:</td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText style="width: 200px" value="#{AjaxTestBacking.string1}">
                            <a4j:support event="onkeyup" action="#{AjaxTestBacking.updateString1}" reRender="string1panelLabel,string1panelValue"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>                    
                          <h:panelGroup id="string1panelLabel">
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{AjaxTestBacking.displayString1Xform}">
                              string1 reversed:
                            </h:panelGroup>
                          </h:panelGroup>                                          
                       </td>
                        <td>
                          <h:panelGroup id="string1panelValue">
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{AjaxTestBacking.displayString1Xform}">
                                <h:outputText style="width: 200px" value="#{AjaxTestBacking.string1Xform}" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                          </h:panelGroup>                                                                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <tr>
```

Note that the panelGroup renders a span here, and the result is not legal html since span cannot exist between tr tags. Instead, the panelGroup should be within a td tag in the table. So, you'd have to have two sets of nested panelGroups to get around the problem. Alternatively, you could replace the html table with an h:panelGrid which generates an html but is friendlier to JSF.

As a side note, I use ui:fragment in JSF 2.1 since it makes the intention of showing/hiding that part of the screen more obvious than a panelGroup.

Comment: Thank you this has solved the issue of the span not showing/hiding! Progress! Now I just need to figure out why the panelgroup is displaying as a span above the table instead of inline.

Comment: ... because the app is break html rules. A panelGroup can render into a span or a div. Neither of these tags are legal where you have them (that is between tr tags). The panelGroup should be inside of the td. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer. You can't have a div or a span inbetween tr tags, and there's no jsf tag for a tr element - it seems you have to do the whole table the jsf way or not at all (to prevent bad design like what's in my app). I have tried substituting with ui:fragment, but it doesn't seem to be ajax-aware (there is no DOM element to re-render), and wrapping the rows in a <a4j:ouputPanel> with layout="none" didn't work either. I guess the real answer is to 'de-tabularize' the form, then I can go back to using <h:panelGroup>.